# Java: Org.JSON Library writes inconsistent datatypes

Tags: java, json, types

I read and write a set of numerical values to a JSON file - they are all the 'double' datatype in Java. An example is the following:

```
double length = 22.4
double height = 13.1
double width = 17.9
double mass = 15.0
```

A JSONArray, 'objects', will then contain JSONObjects, each of which will contain the above measurements. Using the same values as above, it will look something like this (pay attention ot the datatypes):

```
"objects" : 
    [
        {
            "length" : 22.4,
            "width" : 17.9,
            "height" : 13.1,
            "mass" : 15
        }
    ]
```

The first issue posed by such a document is the fact that reading 'length', 'width' and 'height' will return a datatype 'BigDecimal' which seems unnormal for the org.json library which to my knowledge only returns double and integer. This is a problem because I need to convert the 'BigDecimal' values back to double although I wrote the JSON object using standard java double values. Additionally, the org.json library seems to convert any 'double' datatypes to integers when read (notice how mass is '15' and not '15.0'? This is a problem because as you can probably tell, the numerical value of "mass" may be different for another JSONObject (and thus indeed be a double). You can probably imagine the hell, that is iterating through this JSONArray when random values are an integer...

In summary, my problem is the fact that reading JSON files with the org.json library means that numerical values are only returned as doubles or BigDecimals. My question is if I can specify what datatype I would like org.json to write? **All I want, is to read and write all my numerical values as a double - I don't want org.json to choose which datatype it will write to the JSON file.**

My ideas were the following:

- Writing everything as a string and converting back to double when reading
- 

My attempts to solve this that haven't worked or are redundant to me:

- Using the valueOf method to change between datatypes
- Writing 9999 conditions to find the right instances to convert back to double (which sucks)
- Using doubleValue() method

Comment: Please share the relevant code so I can try it at my end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> All I want, is to read and write all my numerical values as a double - I don't want org.json to choose which datatype it will write to the JSON file.

<sup>For what it is worth, the JSON library is not choosing a data type.  It is choosing a character based representation to express a value.  And there is some logical justification for it doing what it is doing.  JSON is (or at least originated as) a subset of Javascript.  In Javascript, integer and floating point are not distinct types.  There is just one primitive data type for all numbers in Javascript.</sup>

I don't think that this can be solved using the `org.json` code.  The stripping of trailing zeros after a decimal point happens in the static `JSONObject::numberToString`.  Since it is a static method, you can't override it in a subclass.

(Take a look at the [source code](https://github.com/stleary/JSON-java/blob/master/src/main/java/org/json/JSONObject.java).)

My suggestions:

1. Work with the current behavior.  For example, your code could be written *know* which fields are supposed to have floating point values, and use `doubleValue()` to retrieve their values.
2. Find an alternative JSON library that doesn't do this.  (Based on my reading of the code, I think Jackson would be OK.  I haven't checked any other libraries ...)
3. You could create your own **private** fork of the `org.json` library and modify it, but then you would be stuck with the overhead of maintaining that fork indefinitely.

I think that 3 is a bad idea.  I have only included it for completeness.